# Can anyone tell me why is node not recognizing my environment variable?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I have a sendgrid API key. I placed it into a dot.env file inside a config folder.
Bud when I try to use it to set api key:

```
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

Node keeps telling me `API key does not start with "SG."`
If I try to `console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)` it gives me undefined.
inside dev.env file:
`SENDGRID_API_KEY=myapikey`

I also have a PORT variable inside this folder and it is used without problems, so it is not a matter of a path to the file. It is not a typo either.

Comment: Are you using the `dotenv` module?  I don't think this happens automatically [Easy-loading Environment Variables in Node](https://sendgrid.com/blog/node-environment-variables/).  Although that article is from 2013, so maybe things have changed.

Comment: I do not have that module. But why does my PORT variable work? It is in the same folder, same file.

Comment: For sanity, can you change the port in the `.env` file and make sure the port that it uses changes with it?  Something else may be setting `PORT`.

Comment: When Node executes it already carries a few environment variables from the OS. You can try this with `console.log(process.env)`. Maybe there is a `PORT` definition there.

Comment: http://zetcode.com/javascript/dotenv/   install & follow directions for dotenv module or use some other equivalent that will require/load the env props from your config file

Comment: So, I tried changing. And it is definitely taking my PORT variable from .env file. I console.log(process.env) and there is the value i used in my .env file. If I use dotenv module does that mean I won't need env-cmd module?

Comment: Yup, using dotenv package worked. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using something like the "dotenv" package to read de environment variables from the "dev.env" file? You can't read environment variables in NodeJS without something like that if I am not mistaken. When I learned how to import this kind of variables I was teached to name the file just ".env".

Comment: OK, dotenv package definitely worked. Thanks Thiago.